# ADF Table Selected Row Key is Wrong upon performing an Action

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have 3 TaskFlow, Update Task Flow and View task Flow inside Search task Flow. When the User selects View/Update in Search.jsff the respective Task Flow is called and upon success redirected back to Search.jsff.

Now I've a af:query with af:table inside Search.jsff where each row has link for View More Details and Update. When the user does an update and redirected to search page, upon viewing the details or updating again it always displays 1st row data instead of the highlighted one.
Now If the user clicks the same row or other and then clicks the View Link or Update it works fine.

My guess is selectedRowKeys is lost, How to maintain the selectedRowKeys for the table?
can I maintain it in a scope or global variable ? all my task flow are in viewPageScope.

---

Note : Have edited the name in pictures. All the taskflow are now in "Always Use Existing transaction"

My Main TaskFlow. Search TaskFlow.
[image: Search_TaskFlow]

---

Create TaskFlow.
[image: Create_TaskFlow]

---

Update TaskFlow.

[image: Update_TaskFlow]

Comment: Are you sharing data control among the taskflows or you are passing selected row key as input to taskflows?

Comment: Ya I'm sharing the DC among taskflow.

Comment: Also, do you have a custom selectionListener for results table or you use the default value ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to save the selected row key when a row is selected and then restore it back later :-

Create a selection listener for table

> selectionListener="#{backingBeanScope.mBean.onTableSelect}"

and use it to store the selected row key in a pageFlowScope variable

```
public void onTableSelect(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) {
    JSFUtils.resolveMethodExpression("#{bindings.DepartmentsView.collectionModel.makeCurrent}", null, new Class[]{ SelectionEvent.class }, new Object[]{ selectionEvent });
    RichTable table = (RichTable) selectionEvent.getSource();
    CollectionModel tableModel = (CollectionModel) table.getValue();
    JUCtrlHierBinding adfTableBinding = (JUCtrlHierBinding) tableModel.getWrappedData();
    DCIteratorBinding tableIteratorBinding = adfTableBinding.getDCIteratorBinding();
    String key = tableIteratorBinding.getCurrentRowKeyString();
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("selectedRowKey", key);
}
```

In the getter method of table binding, set current row with the key value stored in pageFlowScope variable

```
public RichTable getSearchTable()
{
    DCBindingContainer dcBindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry() ;
    DCIteratorBinding iter= dcBindings.findIteratorBinding("DepartmentsView1Iterator");
    if (null != AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().get("selectedRowKey"))
    {
      String key  = (String)AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().get("selectedRowKey");
      iter.setCurrentRowWithKey(key.trim());      
      AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("selectedRowKey", null);
    }  
    return searchTable;
}
```

If your managed bean has pageFlow scope then you instead of storing selected key in a scope variable, you can store it in a bean attribute.

Comment: I just put a String in the PageFlowScope and tried accessing the same after performing my action, but it seems to return null.

Comment: "If your managed bean has pageFlow scope then you instead of storing selected key in a scope variable, you can store it in a bean attribute." - Initially I tried doing this, but upon access the bean attr it also returns NULL.

Comment: The pageFlowScope has to be of the main taskFlow, and any variable or bean attribute set there can not be accessed inside the called taskflows. Where did you set the variable/attribute and where you tried to access it?

Comment: Thats my requirement. I need to set the selected key when going from Main TaskFlow to the Called taskFlow and when The called taskflow has completed the task I need to set the selected key back to the calling taskflow. 

What I did is, My Main TaskFlow Bean is set to pageFlowScope and I'm creating an attr in my Bean which I try to set when calling the Called Task Flow and try to retrieve that value( which is null) when returning back to calling TaskFlow.